# Redirect page/subfolder to new domain url without changing url in browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

have been looking for an answer this without any luck (searched everywhere)

Basically, I want to rewrite a page (subfolder) to a new domain without changing the url. The link should stay the same but show the other website

The following below works but it breaks the images as it replaces everything with the old url:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ http://newdomain/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: Is your folder `test` a real folder ? If so, does it contain real files ?

Comment: no, it's just an empty folder. the illusion is to make it seem that it comes from there.

Comment: What do you mean by "it replaces everything with the old url"? mod_rewrite does not alter the body of a http request. What do these image urls look like and why do you believe your rule should match them?

Comment: Unrelated, but if you do not need complex rewrites, you can use `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives instead. It will probably not solve your problem, but if you don't necessarily need to use mod_rewrite, it is usually better to use faster alternatives.